# Relate Rails function/method to html.erb

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm a newby in Rails, and trying to use methods in html.erb instead of writing the same query several times. I've started with "Hello, World"; but, I couldn't even manage to do this. 
What I do;

```
   def Say() 
  "Hello World" 
   end
```

in app/models/sample.rb (sample is the name of the page by the way) and

```
 <% Say   %>
```

in views/samples/index.html.erb. The problem is, obviously, I cannot see anything like "Hello World" on the page. What should I do?

Comment: what you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Define the method in to your `samples_helper.rb` file or `application_helper.rb` file.

Comment: declare say() method in controller try to call it..

Comment: helper also useful

Comment: At the top of your controller declare your method as helper method like `helper_method :your_method_name` and call it from view like `<%= your_method_name %>. try like this

Comment: to see "Hello World" on samples :) @uzaif

Comment: add <%= Say%> in html.erb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things here:

- Don't use brackets is method name.
- Model is only for managing database or accessing some data that needs database processing
- Adding a `@say = 'Hello World'` in  a controller method `def index` and then calling in view `<%= @say %>` will also do the trick, but don't get used to this approach as it commonly leads to bad habits like overuse of controller instead of models and helpers
- For this thing you can use either model or helper (as I guess "say hello" is just a test)

Maybe the best is to start tutorials from scratch and see how it is handled in rails. There are a lots of resources in rails on website: http://railscasts.com.

Even the site hasn't been updated for quite some time, I think the best resource is to start from there, especially for newbies.

Comment: railscasts is in hiatus, though. Or should we say dead? :)

Comment: yea, really? I haven't gone there for 10 years (I am a bit ironic), It still provides valuable resource for all the newbie Rails programmers. Or maybe the best. If it is not updated, it doesn't mean it is automatically obsolete

Comment: The latest episode is from 3 years ago. This is a very big time. I estimate half of the material to be obsolete and all of it to be not up-to-date with current realities. A careful reader/viewer should adjust, of course, but this is not what we expect from a novice. He's busy enough learning the ropes to also have to figure out why the code doesn't work: the material was wrong to begin with, or the tech moved on?

Comment: Yes, but saying half of the material is obsolete is exaggeration. Maybe only 15% of it is obsolete, but even in those cases it explains the logic very well how, and still it counts for the later episodes. Look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq, or http://railscasts.com/episodes/53-handling-exceptions-revised, or http://railscasts.com/episodes/115-model-caching-revised (I picked a random number of them). Perfectly re-usable nowdays as well. Even the service objects - http://railscasts.com/episodes/398-service-objects Nobody still knows how to use it, even now - 3 years later

Answer (score 1):

There is helpers directory. You can create your own modules there or use default one: ApplicationHelper, which should exists in this dir. Let’s create your own module.

The following makes the *Say* helper method available to the view:

```
 module MyCustomHelper
  def say 
   "Hello World" 
  end
end
```

In a view:

```
<%= say %>
```

Add helper module in your controller like(Rails 3):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :my_custom
end
```

or

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 helper_method :my_custom
end
```

Comment: undefined local variable or method `say'. This is what I get.

Comment: define helper in your controller like:
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :my_custom
end